# Name of cells in vba across sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with the following scenario:

If A1 in sheet1 is equal to "W1" how do I make a VBA so B2 in sheet2 is equal to "Goodmorning Monday".
I have to make so if A1 in Sheet1 is changed to "W2" then B2 in sheet2 is equal to "Goodmorning Tuesday".

I have tried the following code:

```
Sub Datesss()

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "W1" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") = "Goodmorning Monday"
```

or

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "W2" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2") = "Goodmorning Tuesday"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the content of A1 (on sheet1) entered manually or via formula?

Comment: Manually in the sense that it is a dropdown with the contents "W1" and "W2"

Comment: What do you understand by "Name"? Are you referring to a named range? Do you only want changing the other sheet/cell **value**? Do you want it doing automatically, when "A1" in "Sheet1" is modified/changed? If automatically, try answering the above question related to the way of the cell value changing.

Comment: I can see now that the change is done manually. In such a case you can use the Worksheet `Change` event. Now, are there many places in "Sheet1" to trigger changing cells in the other sheet, or only the one in discussion?

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: As Simple As It Gets

- Copy the following code to the sheet code module of worksheet `Sheet1`. In the *VBE Project Explorer*, the name not in parentheses is the sheet code name which will also be displayed in the window in VBA, while the name in parentheses is the tab name.
- There is nothing to run, it runs automatically.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim WDays(): WDays = VBA.Array("W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7")
    Dim Days(): Days = VBA.Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", _
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday") _
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me ' worksheet containing this code
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = Intersect(sCell, Target)
    If tCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim tValue As Variant: tValue = tCell.Value
    Dim tIndex As Variant: tIndex = Application.Match(tValue, WDays, 0)
    If IsError(tIndex) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = sws.Parent.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("B2")
    
    dCell.Value = "Good Morning " & Days(tIndex - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, copy the next code in "Sheet1" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
        Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        If Target.Value Like "W?" Then
            If CLng(Mid(Target.Value, 2)) > 0 And CLng(Mid(Target.Value, 2)) <= 7 Then
                sh2.Range("B2").Value = "Goodmorning " & getDayName(Mid(Target.Value, 2)) 'Monday"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function getDayName(dayNo As Long) As String
    Dim arrDaysName: arrDaysName = Split("Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thurstay,Friday,Saturday,Sunday", ",")
    getDayName = arrDaysName(CLng(dayNo))
End Function
```

Change "A1" cell content and check what happens in "Sheet2", "B2" cell...

Of course, it will do something only for suffix numbers between 1 and 7...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in functions in **Code behind sheet**.
Goto your VBA projects (Alt+F11), and then open the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R)
Double Click Sheet1 and code area will show. Then paste this code in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2) = "Goodmorning Monday"
End If
End Sub
```

Whenever any Cell in Sheet1 is changed this code runs. And by checking the Target. Address you can manipulate what ever you want. Remember to save your file as .xlsm ;-)